# How to prevent mousescroll detection during while function is running?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm building a page with fullscreen sections, which, on scroll, slides to the previous or next slide. This is working fine and dandy. The problem is, that my function is fired on mouse scroll, and because I got some animation in the transition between sections, it bugs out if I scroll during this transition.

This is the function without all the actions in it:

```
$(window).on( 'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function ( event ) {
    if( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ) { 

});
```

I tried adding this:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    return false;
```

as the first action within the function, and then the same at the very end, returning true, but it didnt work.

Is there a better way to run my actions on mousescroll, that also works with mobile scrolling (touch). I need to be able to detect if the user is scrolling up or down (Which this function does).

Comment: It seems to me that within the scroll event handler you should check if your are in a transition phase and during this avoid the bug prone part of the scroll event handler.

Comment: I'm very new to jQuery, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you paste the code that does your animations?

Comment: Theres actually too much for me to paste here